# Difference between a Future returning another Future and Not

Tags: design-patterns, return, dart, future

I'm reading [the "Avast, Ye Pirates" example](http://io2014codelabs.appspot.com/static/codelabs/dart-start/#1), and it's very interesting. But, as a college student(no programming experience), it's somewhat difficult to grasp the concept of RETURNING a Future.

What's difference between

this,

```dart
void doStuff() {
  someAsyncProcess().then((msg) => msg.result);
}
```

and this

```dart
Future doStuff() {
  return someAsyncProcess().then((msg) => msg.result);
}
```

Another question: what is (_) parameter? why not just a blank one ( ).

After reading the Pirate example, I have rearranged or rewritten some of its codes, reducing the number of the code lines a third or less. Though it's more interesting to rearrange the example code than just reading it, my codes became disordered more and more, and my brains too. Is there any Dart guideline about how to arrange classes and functions etc. in a file? That is to say, how to structure the entire codes of a program and of a file? not just MVC, but somewhat detailed guidelines. Below is my code rewritten the Pirate example.

I removed some Future syntax in "static void readyThePirates()", but it still works well.

Thank you in advance.

```dart
// Copyright (c) 2012, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
// for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
// BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

import "dart:html";
import 'dart:math' show Random;
import 'dart:convert' show JSON;
import 'dart:async' show Future;


class PirateName {
  static final Random indexGen = new Random();

  static List<String> names = [];
  static List<String> appellations = [];


  String _firstName;

  String _appellation;

  PirateName({String firstName, String appellation}) {
    if (firstName == null) {
      _firstName = names[indexGen.nextInt(names.length)];
    } else {
      _firstName = firstName;
    }
    if (appellation == null) {
      _appellation = appellations[indexGen.nextInt(appellations.length)];
    } else {
      _appellation = appellation;
    }
  }

  PirateName.fromJSON (String jsonString) {
    Map storedName = JSON.decode(jsonString);
    _firstName = storedName['f'];
    _appellation = storedName['a'];

  }

  String get pirateName => _firstName.isEmpty ? '' : '$_firstName the $_appellation';

  String get jsonString => JSON.encode({
      "f": _firstName, "a": _appellation
  });

/* It's original text in Avast example.
static Future readyThePirates() {
var path = 'piratenames.json';
return HttpRequest.getString(path)
    .then(_parsePirateNamesFromJSON);
}
*/
  static void readyThePirates() {
    var path = 'piratenames.json';
    Future future = HttpRequest.getString(path);
    future.then((String jsonString) {
      Map pirateNames = JSON.decode(jsonString);
      names = pirateNames['names'];
      appellations = pirateNames['appellations'];
    });
  }


}


final String TREASURE_KEY = 'pirateName';

void main() {
  getBadgeNameFromStorage();

  PirateName.readyThePirates();

  querySelector('#generateButton').onClick.listen(generateBadge);
  querySelector('#clearButton').onClick.listen(clearForm);
  querySelector('#jsonButton').onClick.listen(getBadgeNameFromJson);


}


void generateBadge(Event e){

  String inputName = querySelector('#inputName').value;
  var myPirate = new PirateName(firstName: inputName);

  querySelector('#badgeName').text = myPirate.pirateName;


  window.localStorage[TREASURE_KEY] = myPirate.jsonString;

  if (inputName.trim().isEmpty) {
    querySelector('#generateButton')
      ..disabled = false
      ..text = 'bra';
  } else {
    querySelector('#generateButton')
      ..disabled = true
      ..text = 'no bra';

  }
}

PirateName getBadgeNameFromStorage() {
  String storedName = window.localStorage[TREASURE_KEY];
  if (storedName != null) {
    PirateName newPirate = new PirateName.fromJSON(storedName);
    querySelector('#badgeName').text = newPirate.pirateName;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

void clearForm(Event e) {
    querySelector('#generateButton').disabled = false;
    querySelector('#badgeName').text = "";
    querySelector('#inputName').value = "";
}

void getBadgeNameFromJson(Event e) {
  var jsonPirate = new PirateName();


  querySelector('#badgeName').text = jsonPirate._firstName + ' the '+ jsonPirate._appellation;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difference in that the asynchronous execution flow in Dart maintained by some internal behavior.

This flow relies on the continuations and a continuations, of course, relies on returning results.

This flow similar to the chain of events (does not confuse them with other events and perceive them literally).

In this chain of events (as and in our real life) can occurs some exceptional situations (exception).

When you do not return result of the asynchronous execution flow (continuation) then you break the chain of events as there is only one way to keep it alive - return a result of continuation, which contains, information about all situations (including exceptional).

When you break the chain you break the execution flow and behavior of your execution will be unpredictable due to lack of control over the exceptional situations.

This means that, if in your continuations (yes, asynchronous operations are just a continuation) occurs exception you already have no control over this situation, because you lose control when you do not return the result (even if you do not need it and use "_").

In fact, "_" is only the name of function parameter (which is a result of the previous (antecedent) computation). You can use any allowed name which you prefer.

So, in conclusion.

```dart
Future foo() {
  // You will lose control over the flow (chain of events)
  new Future(() => throw "Don't miss me, return this future");
}
```

```dart
Future foo() {
  // You pass control over the chain
  return new Future(() => throw "Don't miss me, return this future");
}
```

```dart
Future noUsefulResult() {
   return new Future.value(null);
}

Future<int> baz() {      
  // return noUsefulResult().then((_) => 42); 
  return noUsefulResult().then((INotNeedIt) => 42);
}
```

Comment: Very clear and concise explanation. Thank you mezoni.